# Primal to Dual Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I'm learning how to convert primal LP problems to dual, but not sure if I'm doing it correclty.

primal:
$$
\begin{align}
maximize: \ \ \ \quad x_1 + 2x_2\qquad\quad \ \ \\
subject\ to:\ -2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \qquad & = 2\\
 -x_1 + 2x_2\quad + x_4\quad & = 7\\
 x_1\qquad\qquad\ \  + x_5  & = 3\\
x_i \ge 0, i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
\end{align}
$$

My attempt at the dual:
$$
\begin{align}
minimize: \ \ 2\lambda_1 + 7\lambda_2 + 3\lambda_3\\
subject\ to:\ -2\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 & \ge 1\\
\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2\quad\ \  & \ge 2\\
\lambda_1, \lambda_2\ both\ free,\ & \lambda_3 \ge 0\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You are forgetting a few constraints. Remember that row 0 is $x_1+2x_2+0x_3+0x_4+0x_5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$ \begin{align} maximize: \ \ \ \quad x_1 + 2x_2\qquad\quad \ \ \\
>  subject\ to:\ -2x_1 + x_2 + \color{red}{ x_3} \qquad & = 2 \quad (\color{blue}{\lambda_1})\\  -x_1 + 2x_2\quad +
>  \color{red}{x_4}\quad & = 7\quad (\color{blue}{\lambda_2})\\  x_1\qquad\qquad\ \  + \color{red}{x_5}  & = 3\quad (\color{blue}{\lambda_3})\\ x_i \ge 0, i = 1,
>  2, 3, 4, 5 \end{align} $$

Because of the equality signs all $\lambda_i$ are free. But this is only an intermediate result. The constraints which results from the (red) $\color{red}{ x_i}$ are:

$\lambda_1\geq 0 \quad (\color{red}{ x_3})$

$\lambda_2\geq 0 \quad (\color{red}{ x_4})$

$\lambda_3\geq 0 \quad (\color{red}{ x_5})$

Beside this your dual program is fine.

Comment: So all free $\lambda_i$ are negligent by the end when including constraints from $x_3$ through $x_5$?

Comment: Yes, that´s it.